# How does one create an SVN Maven project?

Tags: java, linux, svn, maven

I just want to make a sample example. I worked with git and I'm new to all that svn stuff. I found these steps of creating an snv project:

```
sudo svnadmin create /home/svn/myproject
sudo chown -R www-data:subversion myproject
sudo chmod -R g+rws myproject
```

And I created a sample maven project (`mvn archetype:generate`). I wonder what is a way of connecting these two projects or copying something from maven project to this `/home/svn/myproject` folder to make it work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The command `svnadmin create` creates a new svn repository. A single repository is meant to hold many projects. Once you have a working repo, I do the following to create a new project.

First, create the initial files you want to import. Let's say '/tmp/newprojfiledir/'.

```
cd /tmp
svn import /tmp/newprojfiledir PATH -m 'your initial checkin comment'
```

Where PATH can be a URL or local directory, which specifies the destination directory of the svn repo.

Comment: That will not work, cause you need to define file:///tmp/new... cause you didn't define a URL.